# How to generate UPC or EAN bar code with xzing java library

Tags: java, barcode

I found the next code that generates QRCODE from a string using google zxing library

```
String textToCodify = "1234567891234";
QRCodeWriter barcodeWriter = new QRCodeWriter();
BitMatrix bitMatrix = barcodeWriter.encode(textToCodify, BarcodeFormat.EAN_13, 200, 200);
File outputfile = new File("image.jpg");
BufferedImage code = MatrixToImageWriter.toBufferedImage(bitMatrix);;
ImageIO.write(code, "jpg", outputfile);
```

But when I've tried to generate UPC or EAN code  I've got some exception raised.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can only encode QR_CODE, but got EAN_13
    at com.google.zxing.qrcode.QRCodeWriter.encode(QRCodeWriter.java:59)
    at com.google.zxing.qrcode.QRCodeWriter.encode(QRCodeWriter.java:44)
    at workWithBarCode.Test.generateQRCodeImage(Test.java:43)
    at workWithBarCode.Test.main(Test.java:23)
```

Can some one help.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution: just use `EAN13Writer` in place of `QRCodeWriter`

```
String textToCodify = "123456789123";
EAN13Writer   eAN13Writer = new EAN13Writer();
//QRCodeWriter barcodeWriter = new QRCodeWriter();
BitMatrix bitMatrix =  eAN13Writer.encode(textToCodify, BarcodeFormat.EAN_13, 210, 100);
File outputfile = new File("image.jpg");
BufferedImage code = MatrixToImageWriter.toBufferedImage(bitMatrix);;
ImageIO.write(code, "jpg", outputfile);
```